# How to install Ubuntu alongside Windows on another partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, 14.10

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on a system that is not solely mine so I want to install Ubuntu alongside the existing Windows system.

I already tried to "Alatnen" [unclear to the editor] but I erased all data on the hard drive.

I want a way to install Ubuntu alongside Windows on another partition.

How should I proceed

Comment: dude your english is not clear. you can write in your mother tongue and then translate it to english from translate.google.com

Comment: @edwardtorvalds how many languages do you speak? :P

Comment: Mohamed: I don't understand "alatnen".  If you don't agree with my edit, add a comment with @Fabby

Comment: @Fabby 3 lang :p

Answer (score 0):

any linux distro will be installed on the another partition.
Try installing Win first(skip it if already done)
then during the installation choose "something else" and make your own partition,

http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hOz66FC0pWU

If Win came pre-installed (i.e. UEFI stuff) you have to be a bit careful though and look for videos on how to install ubuntu in efi mode .

[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)